# Replace multiple named group matches in a single match group

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I am using a Regular Expression to generate SQL from a text file containing "header" (RecordType,Order) and "child" (ProdCode) data. I need a statement for each child entry, not just each header. The file looks something like follows:

```
RecordType:Amend
OrderNo:Order1
ProdCode:Product1
ProdCode:Product2
RecordType:Create
OrderNo:Order2
ProdCode:Product3
ProdCode:Product4
```

from which I would like to get this:

```
insert into #Reset (RecordType, OrderNo, ProdCode) values ('Amend', 'Order1', 'Product1')
insert into #Reset (RecordType, OrderNo, ProdCode) values ('Amend', 'Order1', 'Product2')
insert into #Reset (RecordType, OrderNo, ProdCode) values ('Create', 'Order2', 'Product3')
insert into #Reset (RecordType, OrderNo, ProdCode) values ('Create', 'Order2', 'Product4')
```

I have managed to match and replace each header record with a child using this regex and replacement:

```
^RecordType:(?<RT>.+)$\r\n^OrderNo:(?<ORD>.+)$(\r\n^ProdCode:(?<PID>.+)$)+

INSERT INTO #Reset \(RecordType, strPoNo, strItemNo\) values \('$+{RT}', '$+{ORD}', '$+{PID}'\)
```

Unfortunately this only takes the last `ProdCode` of the group so I end up with the following:

```
insert into #Reset (RecordType, OrderNo, ProdCode) values ('Amend', 'Order1', 'Product2')
insert into #Reset (RecordType, OrderNo, ProdCode) values ('Create', 'Order2', 'Product4')
```

Is there a way to replace all the ProdCodes in one replace operation?

I am using Notepad++ 6.8.1

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a single regx. For such job, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Thanks. Admittedly I did do a 1-liner in .net in the end but good to know.